# Ubuntu thinks I'm on Kali

Tags: custom-distributions

So I installed Kali repos on Ubuntu. Bad idea btw.

They didn't work quite well so I removed them however Ubuntu thinks I'm on Kali?

[image: Screenshot: OS info]

It also broke things like software manager saying no module found "kali"

[image: Screenshot: Python platform info]

Tried dist-upgrade, upgrade, IDK what to do.

Edit for @A.B.:

```
$ grep -r 'kali' /etc/apt
Binary file /etc/apt/trusted.gpg matches
$


void@abyss:~$ apt-cache policy python
python:
  Installed: 2.7.9-1
  Candidate: 2.7.9-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.9-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
void@abyss:~$ apt-cache policy bash
bash:
  Installed: 4.3-14ubuntu1
  Candidate: 4.3-14ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 4.3-14ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Do a fresh install of Ubuntu.

Comment: I'd much rather not. I could've thought of doing that myself.

Comment: Did you do a `sudo apt-get update` before the upgrade commands?

Comment: Yes @ParanoidPanda

Comment: Hard to tell what packages got screwed up. Hmm... first, you could try a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall base-files` to reinstall central files that (among others) contain information on your OS. Beware! This might overwrite some conf files that you modified. Run `dpkg -L base-files` to understand what files will be overwritten. Failing all else: `for pkg in $(dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}'); do sudo apt-get install --reinstall $pkg; done` will reinstall all packages on your system. Be sure to use `--dry-run` first as a sanity check, and use at your own risk. ;-)

Comment: What Kali repositories did you add and how (which commands)?

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa I'm running the for loop, base-files couldn't be reinstalled because they couldn't be downloaded. Don't worry about my sanity lmfaoo it's long gone.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda the basic ones I pulled from kalis online source list lmao IDK how that could have gone wrong *sarcasm* 18 hours in front of a computer screen makes you do stupid things and wonder "hmm wonder if this will work" didn't think it'd work well if at all, also didn't think it'd cause this much of a problem.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `grep -r 'kali' /etc/apt`

Comment: @A.B. the sources are now disabled haha. But for you, sure.

Comment: You are sure a smart guy, but perhaps you should do what I say.

Comment: @A.B. re-read what I wrote lol. Pressed enter before I finished typing...

Comment: @A.B. Done. Neither of em are kali

Comment: An other way, add the Kali repositories again. Start **only** `sudo apt-get update` no upgrades or something else. Run `dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ {print $2}' | xargs apt-cache policy \;` and post the output at http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give me the link. Remove the Kali repositories again and start `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: @A.B. I'll get to it once the command that Malte posted

Comment: Better not, but good luck.

Comment: @A.B. is quite right. That loop is quite dangerous. Better to inspect what happened and take some reasonable action. `dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ {print $2}'` is equivalent to `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | awk '{print $1}'` (I think). Better to run the list through `apt-cache policy` than through `sudo apt-get install --reinstall`. Seriously. Stop the loop and do what the man says. ;-)

Comment: @A.B. From the looks of it only ndiff, nmap, python-scapy, and aircrack are from kali http://paste.ubuntu.com/12993859/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. According to the [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12993859/) of the command `dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ {print $2}' | xargs apt-cache policy \;` you have to downgrade the Kali packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng=1:1.2-0~beta3-4 ndiff=6.47-7 nmap=6.47-7 python-scapy=2.2.0-1
   ```
2. Correct the entries in `/etc/lsb-release`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/lsb-release
   ```

   add replace the content with the lines below

   ```
   DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
   DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.10
   DISTRIB_CODENAME=wily
   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.10"
   ```