# Ubuntu is not Starting, System Running in Low Graphics Error show but it isn't the problem

Tags: grub2, software-sources, kali

Actually I have added the Kali sources list in the ubuntu sources list two days ago. I added that for installing an application. Now after two days my ubuntu machine was giving crash reports, when i restart it, i was shocked that in start at grub it was showing Kali Linux after hitting enter it shows the ubuntu logo then the error System Running in Low Graphics. i tried the all methods i found here to solve system running in low graphics error but couldn't get success.

Thanks in Advance if someone solve my issue :).

Comment: Problems are very much expected when you mix different distro's repositories. There is also no proven way to recover, because users are expected to be smart, and developers have better thing to do then work out mixed repos cases. IMHO, backup files, and reinstall.

Comment: Is there any option to restore it ?

Comment: As said, it's probably not impossible, and yet, there is no known and tested way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu thinks I'm on Kali](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691217/ubuntu-thinks-im-on-kali)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updated Ubuntu 16.04, now I'm running Kali?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834132/updated-ubuntu-16-04-now-im-running-kali)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to boot an earlier linux image selecting advanced options at grub, then select an earlyer version.

Now I'm not sure if you'll be able to repair your system, but booting an older version will probably work, however you'll most likely will not be able to update your system anymore, but if selecting an earlyer version works, then you can try removing kali source, running sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get check, sudo apt-get upgrade, and that COULD be able to repair your system, however you should back up your data before attempting to fix it... older version without updates should work if you're fine with not being able to update it until you re-install...